# получить столбец из подзапроса

Tags: postgresql, select

Есть такой запрос:

```
SELECT * FROM ( SELECT t1.angles, t2.angles, row_number() over() as rn from orient t1, orient t2 limit 10) subquery WHERE rn > 5;
```

При запросе всех строк всё выполняется. Но как запросить только t1.angles или t2.angles ?
Т.е, такой запрос выдает ошибку:

```
SELECT t1.angles FROM ( SELECT t1.angles, t2.angles, row_number() over() as rn from orient t1, orient t2 limit 10) subquery WHERE rn >5;
```

> ОШИБКА: таблица "t1" отсутствует в предложении FROM

Comment: Как в любом случае, когда есть одинаково называющиеся колонки -
 используя алиасы `SELECT angles1 FROM ( SELECT t1.angles as angles1, t2.angles as angles2, `

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
SELECT subquery.angles FROM ( SELECT t1.angles, t2.angles, row_number() over() as rn from orient t1, orient t2 limit 10) subquery WHERE rn >5;
```

Вы пытаетесь обратиться к алиасу `t1` который скрыт от внешнего запроса. Чтобы обратиться к полям подзапроса необходимо обращаться к алиасу `subquery`

Comment: ну, а если мне нужен именно t1.angles? тем более , что приведенный вами пример тоже выдает ошибку: ОШИБКА: неоднозначная ссылка на столбец "angles"

Comment: все потому, что подзапрос возвращает два столбца с одним именем. Сделайте алиасы для стоблцов в подзапросе `SELECT subquery.angles1 FROM ( SELECT t1.angles as angels1, t2.angles as angels2 ...`